# PIL - resizing an image - different numpy array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am reading an image from S3 bucket, then resize the image and get the numpy array of the resized image, called "a".  I also save the resized image and reopen it and get the numpy array of that called "b".  My question is why a and b are different?

```
    resp = s3.get_object(Bucket=event['bucket'], Key=event['image_keys'][0])
    data = resp['Body']
    image_as_bytes = io.BytesIO(data.read())
    image = Image.open(image_as_bytes).convert('RGB').resize((299, 299),Image.NEAREST)
    a = np.asarray(image)
    
    image.save('IMAGE_58990004_110132026B_13d64039_resized_lambda.jpg')
    b = np.asarray(Image.open('IMAGE_58990004_110132026B_13d64039_resized_lambda.jpg'))
```

Does ".save" changes the numpy array?

Comment: Unable to reproduce based on information provided

Comment: Based on the provided answer, I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: Answer makes a good guess about your situation, but that does not remove the need to ask a proper question with a [mcve]

Comment: Agree.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `image.save(...)` uses the filename ending (`.jpg`) to pick a file format (I don't know if it does. but it seems reasonable), then you are saving as a JPEG file, and the JPEG compression algorithm is lossy, i.e, it discards some information to make the file smaller.

Try using a file format with lossless compression, such as PNG.